# event.preventDefault() and return false; are failing me

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I think I am just too tired right now but why is this not working?
Got a simple form with id="contact"

```
   $("#contact").on('submit', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       var name = $('#name').serialize();
       var email = $('#email').serialize();
       var message = $('#message').serialize();
       alert(name);

        }); 
    });
```

(I stripped out the AJAX that follows)
Why isnt' the window prevented from refreshing? return false; didnt do anything either..
I am probably missing something obvious here

Comment: You should edit your snippet to fix highlighting :p -

Comment: What kind of element is #contact?

Comment: Try $("#contact").live('submit', function(event) { ... } in case your selector is executing before doc ready or form is loaded after the selector

Comment: @Udan No, live() is deprecated and replaced by on().

Comment: Most likely there's a syntax error in the script (perhaps the extra `});`?) Run the JavaScript through JSLint or something similar.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but is "event" a valid variable name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$(document).on('submit', "#contact", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var name = $('#name').serialize();
   var email = $('#email').serialize();
   var message = $('#message').serialize();
   alert(name);
   return true; 
});
```

Comment: Don't downvote this. In case the form is dynamically generated, this is the way to go.

Comment: The form isn't dynamically created.

Comment: $('#name').serialize() should be $('#name').val() ... , the .serialize() method is for forms, not for fields.

Answer (score 0):

The first point:

- You should use .val() instead of serialize() .
- .serialize() is a method applicable to the  element, this method returns a string like this : field1=value1&field2=value2&...&fieldn=valuen

An example:

```
$("#contact").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val(),
        email = $('#email').val(),
        message = $('#message').val();

    alert(name);
    return false; // "Defensive" line (i think it's not necessary)
});
```

I hope it will help!